# This page isn’t working , redirected you too many times. django

Tags: django, nginx

When I run **python manage.py runserver** the server runs fine.

But the web page show the redirection. I have attached the image link below.

how can I resolve the issue?

[redirected you too many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCNaf.png)

Comment: Likely you redirect to the same URL and hence it keeps triggering redirects until the browser has enough of it.

Comment: another server admin.idesk360.com works fine. but devadmin.idesk360.com.
not ok. how is it possible?